# Porting polynomial regression from R to python

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am trying to replicate a polynomial regression from R to python, but I am not getting the same results:

R example:

```
x = seq(1,100)
y = x^2 + 3*x + 7
fit = lm(y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE))
> fit

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))

Coefficients:
            (Intercept)  poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)1  poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)2  
                      7                        3                        1
```

Python example

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> x = np.arange(1,101)
>>> y = x^2 + 3*x + 7
>>> fit = np.polyfit(x,y,2)
>>> fit
array([  2.14390707e-02,   1.00652305e+00,   3.49914904e+01])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `x**2` it is in python

Comment: @cel thanks! that was it ! Please put your comment as an answer so I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the completeness as @cel didn't put it as answer yet.
You have to write  `y = x**2 + 3*x + 7` in python